# Pure JavaScript - Hide Div on Clicking outside

Tags: javascript, css

I want when i click outside the **My DIV** with the ID `Container_ID` , all the Container gets hidden through `display: none;`. The code that i present in **JavaScript** works to a certain point, because when i click inside any part of the `Container_ID` it returns the same behavior, the **My DIV** hides. And it wasn't supposed when i'm interacting with elements `Controls_CLASS` + `ul,li` + `Checkbox_CLASS` inside the `Container_ID` itself. They should be excluded from hiding the entire `Container_ID` when i click on them, because they are inside.

How can I improve this?

**JavaScript** (font: https://codepen.io/marizawi/pen/YgaaMp)

```js
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  var cont = document.getElementById('Container_ID');
  if (event.target != cont && event.target.parentNode != cont) {
    cont.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
div.Container_CLASS {
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container_CLASS" id="Container_ID">
  <div class="Controls_CLASS"><a href="#">Select All</a>|<a href="#">Reset</a></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="BMW" />BMW</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Mercedes" />Mercedes</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Volvo" />Volvo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it visible in a [mcve]

Comment: Also [surely a dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=hide+div+click+outside+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I don't understand what's not working. I don't see a list anywhere in the sample.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, it's a dupe but none of the top 3 search results I checked had really good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this work.
use `closest` method to check clicked outsde div.

### [closest](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom)

Ancestors of an element are: parent, the parent of parent, its parent and so on. The ancestors together form the chain of parents from the element to the top.

The method `elem.closest(css)` looks for the nearest ancestor that matches the CSS-selector. The `elem` itself is also included in the search.

In other words, the method `closest` goes up from the element and checks each of parents. If it matches the selector, then the search stops, and the ancestor is returned.

if `div` has `id`

```js
 window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event){
        var pol = document.getElementById('pol');
        if(!(event.target.closest("#pol"))){
            pol.style.display = 'none';
        }
  });
```

```css
h2{margin:0 0 10px}
#pol{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background:#999;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    margin-top:0;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click outside div will be hide. Click Button div will be display</h2>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('pol').style.display='block'">Show</button>
<div id="pol">
I am Tanmoy Biswas
  <p>ksjdhfksjdhfkjshdfkjsdfsf</p>
<div class="Controls_CLASS"><a href="#">Select All</a>|<a href="#">Reset</a></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="BMW" />BMW</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Mercedes" />Mercedes</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Volvo" />Volvo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

if `div` has `class` :

```js
 

    window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
  let pol = document.querySelectorAll(".pol");
  pol.forEach((myDiv) => {
    if (!(event.target.closest(".pol"))) {
      myDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
h2{margin:0 0 10px}
.pol{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background:#999;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    margin-top:0;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click outside div will be hide. Click Button div will be display</h2>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('a').style.display='block'">Show</button>
<div id="a" class="pol">
I am Tanmoy Biswas
  <p>ksjdhfksjdhfkjshdfkjsdfsf</p>
<div class="Controls_CLASS"><a href="#">Select All</a>|<a href="#">Reset</a></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="BMW" />BMW</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Mercedes" />Mercedes</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Volvo" />Volvo</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<h2>Click outside div will be hide. Click Button div will be display</h2>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('b').style.display='block'">Show</button>
<div id="b" class="pol">
I am Tanmoy Biswas
  <p>ksjdhfksjdhfkjshdfkjsdfsf</p>
<div class="Controls_CLASS"><a href="#">Select All</a>|<a href="#">Reset</a></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="BMW" />BMW</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Mercedes" />Mercedes</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Volvo" />Volvo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `event.target.closest("#pol") === null` can be replaced by `!(pol.contains(event.target))`.

Comment: @connexo which one is More efficient ?

Comment: @M.RMRF, in don't have #pol , my container are created as a class on CSS and not as an ID, `.Container_CLASS` and not `#Container_CLASS` . Your example works on snippet but not when i trasnport for my real code. :s

Comment: @Jaakko i edit answer. Can it help?

Comment: @M.RMRF , what you mean with `myDiv` , i have nothing on my example with this name ...

Comment: @Jaakko `myDiv` is an Argument that pass any items with `.pol` class to `foreach fallback function`

Comment: @M.RMRF , now it works with the behavior that i want :) TY

Comment: @M.RMRF , please help me with a last thig, why `Toggle_Visibility` now only shows the DIV and don't close if i click again? Why my funcion `kDMC_Toggle_Visibility` now just works for open it. please check directly my code here:  https://imgur.com/a/J7NCLRe

Comment: @jaakko the image is not clear. and that's better to post another question with code sample. can you put your code in online editors?

Comment: @M.RMRF, now when the `Checkbox List (Toggle)` is clicked, the `Container_ID` just opens, if i click again it's supposted to hide and it not happens anymore. please check the code results here: https://liveweave.com/ed6Feq#&togetherjs=Rwbxv1RNps

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241332/discussion-between-m-r-mrf-and-jaakko

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do.

Simply check if the element clicked (`event.target`) is in the container, or if the `event.target` is the element that shows the container.

```js
const theDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
const theButton = document.getElementById('theButton');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (theDiv.contains(event.target) || event.target.id === 'theButton') return;
  theDiv.hidden = true;
})
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="this.nextElementSibling.hidden=false" id="theButton">Show</button>
<div hidden id="theDiv">
  <button>clicking here won't close</button>
</div>
```

For your example:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('Container_ID');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (container.contains(event.target)) return;
  container.hidden = true;
})
```

```css
div.Container_CLASS {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container_CLASS" id="Container_ID">
  <div class="Controls_CLASS"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Select All</a>|<a href="javascript:void(0)">Reset</a></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="BMW" />BMW</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Mercedes" />Mercedes</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Volvo" />Volvo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: on the snippet works pretty good, but when i put on my code , don't do anything :s

Comment: Adapted to your code. Works.

Comment: i can see it working on snippet again, but on my real code won't work. the `Container_ID` are inside a form, and an table TD, could be the problem? or does it not interfere?

Comment: Are you sure your page doesn't have duplicate `id="Container_ID"`?

Comment: for sure.. by the way, the real name is `id="pActividade--div"` ... i just have one, as i show you on the example.

Comment: Then replace `ContainerID` by `document.getElementById('pActividade--div')` in the code.

Comment: still not working, please check directly on my code, may you find something wrong: https://imgur.com/a/q2DVrKH

Comment: The code works. You need to **not have** any `display` property set in your CSS for the container, otherwise you destroy the `hidden` functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few options you could use

The best IMO is the mouse leave event

## On Mouse Leave

```js
document.getElementById("Container_ID").addEventListener('mouseleave',function(event){
    document.getElementById("Container_ID").style.display = "none";
});
```

## On Focus Out

```js
document.getElementById("Container_ID").addEventListener('focusout',function(event){
    document.getElementById("Container_ID").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: both doesn't work. When i click outside the `Container_ID`, the same wont's hide.